# Importing Group Audience data

Tags: organic-groups, feeds, migrations

I have a site using OG7 and created groups to let users to access to some content as per the user membership and concent-type membership as well.

Each user has to belong to a group and I can select that group(s) for him/her in the corresponding Group-Audience list box when adding or editing user information.  I have also created content-types which should be attached to a group via Group-Visibility and Group-Audience Fields.  When creating content, let's say an Event, I just select in the group-audience list the group I want that event to stick to and also I choose private as the group visibility choice.

Now, the problem is that I need to import a huge number or nodes of different content types, say Events, and each one has to be associated to a group.  Currently I just import the content-type data using feeds modules (feeds-import) using a CSV file and once in Drupal I do the group associations by hand. I cannot find a way to import the content-type along with group association while importing the data, also I don't know how to do it directly in the database, I tried but it didnt work.  Anyone of you know how to import group-audiences? anyone knows which tables are affected when associating a group to a content-type?  Thanks in advance for your time in assisting me.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to import a lot of different content types

you might want to check the [Migrate Module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) out

It supports Organic Groups.

[Migrate Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1133448)

// Maybe this can help you some of the way

[Migrate Classes: Location CCK to Address Field](http://grasmash.com/article/migrate-classes-location-cck-address-field)

[Migrate Extras](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_extras)

This might also give you a clue on how to do it. I know its

[Migrate OG](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_og)